# How can I replace a collection with PUT using express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to take a json collection of data and send it with postman or Advanced REST Client. The biggest thing I'm getting stuck with with is where the data is. I can't seem to find it in any part of the request. Note this must be done using express.

```
app.put('/api/', function (req, res) {
    //Get data and replace table in database
    res.send("RECEIVED");
});
```

Comment: How are you making the PUT request, and what have you tried in the context of your route handler? Have you tried applying what the official express.js documentation explains?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please describe about what database you are using and what you have tried so far. Please put these details in your question along with the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use `body-parser` to parse the request and provide you all that submited data through `request.body.data`  if you send you data as a form-data or `request.params.data` if you send your data as a query parameter.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

And import it and use it as a middleware

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// some other code goes here like 
// var express = require("express"):
// var app = express()


// and here attach the body-parser middleware like thiss
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

when you make a request with any Advanced REST client each key in the JSON that you pass to the request body will be accessible as `request.body.key` you can learn more about body-parser [body-parser doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)